# Can a particle tunnel from inside a black hole?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, black-holes, ads-cft, event-horizon, quantum-tunneling

Event horizon isn’t special from GTR standpoint, and at least in AdS/CFT correspondence gravity can be “removed” from consideration entirely. So can a particle whose wave function is completely inside a black hole at some point in time “smear” to the outside and end up being observed there just by tunneling? I’m not a physicist, so feel free to make any corrections to the question.

Comment: I can't guarantee that answer since I do not know if it has been done for that exact case, but generally speaking, quantum fields cannot affect anything outside of their own light cone. As anything inside a black hole would only have its light cone inside the horizon, I do not think you'd be able to tunnel out for this reason.

Comment: I feel like in order to answer this question we'd need a quantum theory of gravity, which we don't have.

Comment: see my answer to a duplicate here https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/482651/